# Kafka MM2 stop automatic replicated topic creation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Working on KafkaMM2 with Kafka 2.13.3.0.0

Is there any way to disable topic creation from source cluster to target cluster without impacting any other MM2 feature (Like : offset syncing, record syncing etc...)

Want to create replicated topics manually instead of automatically only.

Comment: What do you mean by `disable topic mirroring`? You then say you want `record syncing`, aren't these the same thing? Do you mean disable automatically creating remote topics in the target cluster?

Comment: I mean disable automatically creating remote topics only in target cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a good documentation for the Mirrormaker configuration parameters, but it is usually possible to puzzle them together with the [KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0) and the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/4b310d1fe171d6d5edda13bb1baf2cf5a0d8eb68/connect/mirror/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/MirrorConnectorConfig.java)

IIRC is should be enough to set

```
sync.topic.configs.enabled = false
```

in your Mirrormaker config